# How to get the text in a particular div only avoiding the text from nested divs?

Tags: javascript, html, text, get

I have a nested div structure as follows

```
    <div id =a>
      my content
    <div id =a1>
      irrelevant content
    </div>

    <div id= a2>
      irrelevant content
    </div>

    </div>
```

I know I can get the innerText of the div with id `"a"` as `document.getElementById('a').innerText` but that will give me something like 
`my content irrelevant content irrelevant content` but I want only the content that is in that particular div instead of it concatenated with the contents of the nested divs.How do I get it?

Comment: `document.getElementById('a').childNodes[0]`

Comment: `innerText` does not work in Mozilla.  Use `textContent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the direct child nodes and filter for those that are so called 'text nodes' (i.e. they contain text, and are not tags).

```
var element = document.getElementById('a'),
result = "";
for (var i=0; i<element.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3) {
        result += element.childNodes[i].textContent;
    }
}
```